Abaqus - How to select thousands of XY data from Excel Utilities
while using Abaqus if I want to export some data to Excel I use the "Excel Utilities" plugin.
However, while doing this I didn't find a way, if there is one, to select all the data to export at once.
If you look at the attached image, I have thousands of XY data to plot and from the Excel Utilities dialog I have to select the data one by one. I ctrl + A, shift with down arrow, shift with END button, but none of them works.
Do you know if there is another shortcut to select the entire list of data? Or is there a place where I can request this feature?


You can do this by: First click on the first XY data point in that table --> scroll down at the bottom of the table --> now click shift key and click on the last XY data point. Let me know, if it does not work.

Hi @SatishThorat, thank you. I tried that too but it doesn't work. It just select the last element

Yeah. I think, that's selection limitation of table content of "Excel Utilities" plugin. 
You can use this simple python code snippet to extract the data of "XY Data" objects into a text file. You can further modify it to get the data in excel or csv format.
out_filename = 'xy_data.dat'
fout = open(out_filename, 'w')

xy_dobjs = session.xyDataObjects

for k, v in xy_dobjs.items():
    fout.write(k + '\n')
    for data in v.data:
        fout.write('%.6f,%.6f\n' % data)

fout.close()

OR
You can use make use of "Report" --> "XY" option.

